# Can a database detect that data is out of sequence if each datapoint has a sequential ID

Tags: database-design

Can a database detect that data is out of sequence if each datapoint has a sequential ID? 
E.G A trading DB server receives trade ID 9, and next receives trade ID 11. In this case, I would like the DB to return an error because trade ID 10 is missing. Is this possible? I don't need the code, just some context and the name of the solution. E.G. would this be some sort of DB input validation command, and how would it be enabled?

Comment: Why not simply check this before insertion?  It will be a relatively simple query, I guess.  But you won't find a builtin solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird question. If you don't set a sequential ID as autonumber/autoincrement but sequence must not break, you should code it yourself.
**a)** Don't allow user-entry for the field and add a (max(field)+1) either by an insert trigger or Stored Proc. (BTW it's always a good idea to deny direct access to tables and all insert/update/etc is done by e.g. SPs).
**b)** If must allow users to add field's value, validate it (*insert trigger or even better if it's an "insert SP" with validation logic -- just as I described above*) and rollback insert if ID is not prevID+1.
But what's the point? What is your goal with this 'sequence logic' you are about to implement?
If "trade data" you mention must be in sequence but it's not always true you should look into the *business logic* to see
**1)** why and how the sequence breaks
**2)** what is the best behavior of app/db if it happens (from a business point of view! - e.g. renumber? throw error but still save data? save data with timestamp and maintain data integrity at the end of the day? etc)
**3)** how to avoid this -if possible- to happen in the future
So IMHO focus on business logic and customer requirements, figure out what fits best their needs then code that.

Comment: There are at least one country in the world where the invoice numbers issued by a company must be contiguous (and in order).  Which does not make sense, I admit.

Comment: The data is coming from a live feed and being written to a DB. The DB would have to recognize 1) duplicate ID's (accidentally recording the same trade twice) or 2) skipped ID's (which would imply a trade was not recorded)

Trade ID's must be contiguous and in sequential order and if they are not, it implies some sort of recording error.

Comment: So data get stored but error is logged, right? I'd stay with SP solution. Write an SP which does the INSERT (apps call this from the outside -table access must be disabled) and SP can both record the error in table and throw the error (by returning an error number and some description)

Comment: Mark, thanks, this answers my question and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the sequential IDs that are coming to you and you just need to detect gaps, then you can **use the following query to find the gaps:**

```
create table SEQUENTIAL_THING
( ID int
, ETC varchar(10)
)

insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (1, 'AAA');
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (2, 'BBB');
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (3, 'CCC');
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (4, 'DDD');
-- There is a missing transaction here (ID=5)
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (6, 'FFF');
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (7, 'GGG');
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (8, 'HHH');
-- There is a missing transaction here (ID=9)
-- There is a missing transaction here (ID=10)
-- There is a missing transaction here (ID=11)*/
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (12, 'LLL');
insert SEQUENTIAL_THING (ID, ETC) VALUES (13, 'MMM');

select
  A.ID + 1 as GapStart
, B.ID - 1 as GapEnd
, B.ID - A.ID - 1 as GapLength
from SEQUENTIAL_THING A, SEQUENTIAL_THING B
where A.ID + 1
      = (select max(C.ID + 1)
         from SEQUENTIAL_THING C
         where C.ID + 1 <= B.ID)
  and (B.ID - 1 >= A.ID + 1);

-- Results:
--
-- GapStart  GapEnd  GapLength
-- --------  ------  ---------
-- 5         5       1 
-- 9         11      3
```

Try it out here on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ee58/9)